# What is the slope of the line that passes through the points (−1,−7) and (−13,−7)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help ! For finding slope Im getting upset any answers ?

Comment: both points are on the line $y = -7$ and what is the slope of the line $y = -7?$

Comment: I think I see why you are upset, but please make the body of the Question as self-contained as possible (not relying solely on the title to convey what is being asked).

Comment: try plotting the points on a some graph paper.

Answer (score 2):

$(x_1,y_1)=(-1,-7)$ and $(x_2,y_2)=(-13,-7)$. Since $y_1=y_2$ therefore this line is parallel to x-axis. Hence slope is zero.

Answer (score 1):

$m=\dfrac{-7-(-7)}{-13-(-1)}=0$